# retrying.RetryError: RetryError[Attempts: 1289627, Value: None]

Tags: python

I am trying to use [retrying](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) module as below but running into retrying.RetryError: whenever the `stop_max_delay` is encountered,appreciate if anyone provide inputs on how to fix it?

```
import time
from retrying import retry    
def retry_if_result_none(result):
    """Return True if we should retry (in this case when result is None), False otherwise"""
    return result is None

@retry(stop_max_delay=10000,retry_on_result=retry_if_result_none)
def might_return_none():
    print "Retry forever ignoring Exceptions with no wait if return value is True"

print "Start : %s" % time.ctime()
might_return_none()
print "End : %s" % time.ctime()
```

ERROR:-

```
  File "check_devices.py", line 15, in <module>
    might_return_none()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\retrying.py", line 214, in call
retrying.RetryError: RetryError[Attempts: 1289627, Value: None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like below

```
from retrying import retry, RetryError

try:
    might_return_none()
except RetryError as e:
    print "RetryError"
    print "End : %s" % time.ctime()
```